# R on Ubuntu 14.04: Error in pdf("Plot.pdf") : cannot open file

Tags: r, pdf, plot, jpeg

I'm following textbook instructions to create a file using R and save a plot to it.  When I try to make a pdf I get an error immediately:

> pdf("Plot.pdf")
>   Error in pdf("Plot.pdf") : cannot open file 'Plot.pdf'

When I try to make a jpeg it gives no error, although I can't find the file on my computer, but when I try to write the plot to it I get the same kind of error.

> jpeg("Plot.jpeg")
>   plot(x,y,col="green")
>   Error in plot.new() : could not open file 'Plot.jpeg'

Could it have something to do with using R on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Please add your code for these two scenarios. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had entered R from etc/apt where I was altering sources.list to install R.  I guess R could not make the files in that folder because it's a special system folder and is protected.  Once I returned to my home folder and entered R again everything worked fine.

Comment: Please just delete the question,